# Rewrite rule only for the same part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, rule

I need to make a redirect from URL's:

`RewriteRule    ^/cars/new/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$        /cars/new/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]` - it works.

But, the pages like `/cars/new/asd/qwe/zxc.html` are also redirecting with this rule.

And i need to redirect only URL's like /cars/new/asd/**qwe**/***qwe***.html

And not the /cars/new/asd/**some_part**/ **some_other_part**.html

only /cars/new/asd/**some_part**/ **some_part**.html

Any suggestions please !

updated:
Worked solution is

```
RewriteRule ^cars/new/(.*)/(.*)/\2.html$    /cars/new/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is there a pattern you want to match or is it just fixed directory/file names?

Comment: Oh I see. The filename in the last directory will always match the directory name (but with .html appended), and you want to redirect them to the same directory but without any file name (*/cars/new/part1/part2/part2.html* -> **/cars/new/part1/part2/**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this regex. It uses back references to match the filename with same name as the directory name.

```
RewriteRule ^/cars/new/(.*)/(.*)/\2\.html$ /cars/new/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```